# Need a cam for photos with with flash light for PC

Tags: camera

I am writing a program that needs to take (HD) photos from a camera connected to a computer. That camera also needs an integrated flash light. But I don't really know what I need to look for - when I search for something like "*camera with flash light usb*" I just find some web cams, not what I am looking for.

Do you know any good such camera, or at least what I need to search for online?

PS: It does not have to be connected via USB, that was just my first guess. I am open for other types of PC interfaces/cables as well.

Comment: Would something like [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) with a USB connected DSLR camera work? If you need something that is durable for factory/industrial environments then you have to give us more information about the durability requirements.

Comment: I feel like a DSLR is probably overkill. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there are really a ton of options outside of DIY; my recommendation would be to snag something like a Pi, stick an LED ring or standard hot-shoe flash on with a camera, and then send it over the network to the main computer.

Answer (score 1):

By 'Camera with flash light', do you mean a webcam with some kind of lighting?  If so, I recommend the Razer KIYO.     https://www.razer.com/ca-en/gaming-broadcaster/razer-kiyo

Comment: No that is not what I am looking for. I need an industry-grade camera system, as described.

Comment: That really depends on your understanding of "industry-grade"

Comment: @towe Well, as said I don't know what I am looking for in particular, that's why I am asking here. Industry-grade = something not for your average desktop PC, but for installation into a factory or so.

Comment: I agree that "industrial grade" is somewhat unclear. My concern would more just be that the light on the Kiyo is more supposed to be a fill light than a flash and won't be bright enough, but besides that, this seems to be a decent solution.